# Share Session Between Two Websites

Tags: php, session

Hi thanks in advance...
I am Working on a Project, I need some clarification to share data between two sites in a  high secure manner. Currently I am using Form Post to share data. But I think about if there is an option to get site-1 session-data from site-2, because I think using a session is more secure. I don't know how to use a sessions between two sites, but I hope someone here will know.

Like this:
**Site 1 Coding**

```
$_SESSION['customer_id'] = 'XYZ';  
$_SESSION['total_amount'] = '100';  

<a href=https://site2.com/do.php?session_id=<?=$_SESSION['session_id']?>>Click Here</a>
```

**Site 2 Code in do.php**

```
$session_id = $_REQUEST['session_id'];  
$shared_data = bla_bla_bla_function($session_id);  

$customer_id = $shared_data['customer_id'];  
$total_amount = $shared_data['total_amount'];
```

or is there any way to do the secure data sharing between two website other than form post, please tell me.
Thank you
Yours,
Kaartikeyan R

**Found Solution**

I have send the Customer ID and Amount via CURL to the Second Website, in that create a Record in Table for this and generate Encrypted ID with the Record ID, and return the encrypted ID.

So in the First website i get the Encrypted ID, and use it on URL redirection to Second website.

On the Second Website with the Encrypted ID i get the Customer ID and Amount.

Comment: Try keeping everything that needs to share sensitive data in one place.

Comment: Store the session in a database that is accessible form both server

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Urk.  First off, **never, EVER** do this:

```
$session_id = $_REQUEST['session_id'];
```

This causes a security truck-hole we refer to as 'session fixation' ( read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation ).

It seems you're pretty heavy on security.  If you need to share data from site 1 to site 2, you should do it through a single consumption bridge:

1).  Click on a link on Site 1 to a handler file, let's call it redir.php.

2).  Redir.php first checks the existing session data.

3).  Redir.php writes relevant info into a DB row, along with some sort of identifier (say, an MD5 hash of the user ID + '_'+ current time), plus a 'consumed' flag, set false.

4).  Redir.php does a 301 redirect to Site 2, along with the identifier.

5).  Site 2 reads the relevant row out of the DB.

6).  If the data is good and has not yet been 'consumed', return a success and mark the data as consumed.

7).  If the data has been consumed, throw some sort of error.

There are more complex ways of doing this, but I think this handles what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would upvote the "Urk. First off, never do this:", but then I'd have to downvote for even suggesting it. You know they won't read your warnings...

Comment: ah, I apologise. I didn't see that was their suggestion. +1 for the warning

Comment: On your suggestion, I bolded up the 'never, ever' part.  : )

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I working on a document manager where the file can be hosted on a seperate server and I didn't want users to be able to share a link to download the files, great answer :) Why are you using an isConsumed flag as opposed to just deleting the row?

Comment: @Gazillion - Because I almost never delete rows.  It is a bad model to get into the habit of, especially when tracking & reporting all of a sudden becomes important... and you realize you've thrown away 3 years worth of data.  : )

Answer (score 1):

you could use a common session backend for both sites, eg. store the session in a database

to replace the built-in file backend you can use the function [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)