# How to make 2 different websites connect to 1 username

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

We are creating a socialmedia network for Reddcoin Cryptocurrency http://reddcoin.online Now we want to make a website where users can sell digital goods or services. We want users to be able to login in both websites trough 1 login account (The main account from reddcoin.online) Now the question is how to make another website connect to the same login?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679007/share-session-between-two-websites

Comment: Sounds like it's time to hire a contractor to figure this out. If you get it wrong you will have nothing but regrets: Tiny, innocent mistakes are often punished severely in the crypto space.