# PHP session lost after 2nd redirect but not first

Tags: php, session, kohana-3.3

I have a PHP project, which also has a Kohana PHP project in a subfolder on the site "/reports".

I redirect to the reports project like so:

**redirectreports.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Location: /reports');
exit();
```

When a user clicks the href link, it opens the above in a new window. On the first click of the link, everything works fine and session data is available in the reports project.

The issue happens when I close the window of reports, and then click the reports link a 2nd time. My session data cannot be found the 2nd time I am redirected to reports.

I have tried passing the session id in the query string and then passing that to `Session::instance('native', $_GET['id']);`

But still get the following error:

`Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data.`

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679007/share-session-between-two-websites ... Looks like a similar issue

Comment: Error is thrown here: https://github.com/koseven/koseven/blob/master/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php#L324 Make dirty hack and check what is in original error, eg by: `throw $e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

The actual issue here was that there was an object being stored in the session data by the "reports" package. Result in a `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` error.

That class wasn't accessible to the core project and so the shared info is stored as an array rather than an object.