# Get login status from Wordpress to laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

Good day, We have 2 Web App -- App1 using Wordpress and App2 using Laravel;
Is there a way for App2 to check if a user is loggedin in App1 using App2? App2 doesn't have login ~ App2 needs to check if theres a user loggedin in APp1 and then get the user info such  as ID, Name, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Session Between Two Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679007/share-session-between-two-websites)

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

I’m not sure I completely understand the question but il try answer it.

It sounds like you are trying to get authentication from one app to the next to retrieve information about the initial login. One way this can be done is using something know as **SAML**. SAML stands for security assertion markup language and is a way of exchanging authentication between two parties or different sites. This would need to be implemented in both apps in order it to work. Wordpress has plugins that support this functionality, I had a quick google and I found miniorange. Larvel also has libraries that support this. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you are asking for, but because App2 does not require logging in your options are fairly limited, and somewhat insecure.

#### Option Number 1

You could add an action hook to Wordpress that will send the user's IP (or some other unique identifier) to App2 once App1 has been logged into. App2 will create a temporary session record for that IP. Then when the user navigates to App2 check if that IP has an active session record.

Advantage: This accomplishes exactly what you asked for.

Disadvantages: This is not a fail-safe solution, since IPs could be shared by multiple machines and an IP could also be masked or forged.

#### Option Number 2

Once a user is logged in to App1 Wordpress will use an action hook to send their session information. App2 will add this to some session table. In addition to that you should add a button/link inside the WP CMS admin panel that, when clicked, redirects the user to App2 by posting that same session information. You can then verify that they indeed came from App1.

Advantage: Provides a more secure and consistent way of verifying the user compared to option number 1.

Disadvantage: The user must use the button/link in the Wordpress admin area to navigate to App2, which adds an extra step to the process.

Answer (score 0):

not a wordpress expert but I believe there is always a cookie used to maintain the session, you can access that cookie in Laravel and can use wordpress cookie decrypter to get auth/user details

or this may help
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/how-to-use-wordpress-authentication-on-non-wordpress-page